# Change post type order and show by publishing date

Tags: wordpress

```
function reorder_my_cpt( $q ) {
  $s = get_current_screen();
  if ( is_admin() && $s->base === 'edit' && $s->post_type === 'casestudies' && $q->is_main_query() ) {
    $q->set('orderby', 'date');
    $q->set('order', 'ASC');
  }
}
```

I use code written above, and want to order post types by their published date, it's working in admin panel, but on the site I see this error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen().**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the `get_current_screen()` call inside the `is_admin()` check, like this:

```
function reorder_my_cpt( $q ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        $s = get_current_screen();
        if ( $s->base === 'edit' && $s->post_type === 'casestudies' && $q->is_main_query() ) {
            $q->set('orderby', 'date');
            $q->set('order', 'ASC');
        }
    }
}
```

That way `get_current_screen()` won't be called on the front end.